# Mostrar fecha en dos label distintos

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta a `SQL`:

```
    public List<Fechas> fechasParaLabel()
    {
        List<Fechas> lista = new List<Fechas>();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            string consulta = "SELECT TOP(1) FechaDesde, FechaHasta, MES, ANO " +
                              "FROM periodos " +
                              "WHERE IdProcesoAdmin=2 AND " +
                              "FechaHasta IS NOT NULL " +
                              "ORDER BY IdPeriodo DESC";
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(consulta, sqlConnection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Fechas fechas = new Fechas();
                            fechas.desde = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FechaDesde"]?.ToString();
                            fechas.hasta = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FechaHasta"]?.ToString());
                            fechas.MES = dr["MES"]?.ToString();
                            fechas.ANO = dr["ANO"]?.ToString();
                            lista.Add(fechas);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Desde el `form` la llamo así:

```
    private void cargarFecha()
    {
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        List<Fechas> lista = conexionSQL.fechasParaLabel();
        lblDesde.Text = lista.ElementAt(0).ToString();
    }
```

Pero eso me carga así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la clase:

```
 class Fechas
    {
        public DateTime desde { get; set; }
        public DateTime hasta { get; set; }
        public string MES { get; set; }
        public string ANO { get; set; }

        public Fechas(DateTime desde, DateTime hasta, string mES, string aNO)
        {
            this.desde = desde;
            this.hasta = hasta;
            MES = mES;
            ANO = aNO;
        }

        public Fechas() { }
    }
```

Quisiera saber como cargar la **fecha desde** en el `lblDesde` y la **fecha hasta** en el `lblHasta` que están dentro del `List` del método `fechasParaLabel()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lblDesde.Text = lista.ElementAt(0).ToString();
```

Muestra el ToString del objeto, ya que la lista es una lista de objetos..

Deberias acceder a las propiedades del objeto, de la forma

```
lblDesde.Text = ((Fechas)lista.ElementAt(0)).desde;
```

Igual, todo ese metodo para obtener esos dos valores esta muy sobrecargado... tu metodo devuelve una lista con un solo objeto?

Dentro del metodo iteras el reader que tiene una sola fila?

Comment: No, tengo que traer los otros dos valores. En total serían 4 valores a devolver, pero me conformaba con ver uno para tener la idea general de cómo hacerlo de manera correcta. Gracias